# Why is the two parameter constructor called when single parameter constructor is expected?

Tags: c#

I have the following two constructors in my base class:

```
protected ExternalSystemException( params Object[] args ) 
    : this( null, null, args ) {}

protected ExternalSystemException( String propertyKeySuffix, 
    params Object[] args ) : this( propertyKeySuffix, null, args ) {}
```

My child class has the following constructor:

```
public InvalidPathToOutputFiles(string invalidPath) 
    : base(invalidPath) {}
```

My client logic instantiates the child class like so:

```
throw new ChildClass( "goofy" );
```

When I step through the logic I unexpectedly end up at the base constructor with the parameters `( String propertyKeySuffix, params Object[] args )`.  I expected the other base class constructor to be called, namely `( params Object[] args )`.

Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: As soon as I hit submit I wanted to take this one back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `string` overload is the best match to the type you are providing to the constructor.  The Params are optional (and Object is ambiguous), so since the second overload has a `string` type that matches the `string` type you are passing, the second overload is selected.